# why linux kernel semaphore down() function is deprecated?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Linux kernel [semaphore's down() function comment](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.32.71/source/kernel/semaphore.c#L50) say

```
  /**
    Use of this function is deprecated, please use down_interruptible() 
    or down_killable() instead. 
  **/
```

Someone please explain it, best wish to you.

Comment: Because thread stuck in it can not be cleanly interrupted and may, possibly, linger "forever", until the system is rebooted.

Answer (score 1):

It is explained in comments for down_interruptible and down_killable

TLDR; down doesn't allow you to interrupt when it is sleeping i.e. didn't got semaphore. where as these two exits with -EINR so responsive code.

understand the use of this function down()
Acquires the semaphore.  If no more tasks are allowed to acquire the
semaphore, calling this function will put the task to sleep until the
semaphore is released. that means it will not be interrupted if calling process got interrupted. or killed. underlying logic differs in [second argument to _down_common()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.32.71/source/kernel/semaphore.c#L241)

So it is suggested to use any of two suggestion so that it can be processed in case of interrupt. Also no use of keeping it after calling process got killed.

Major thing deprecated function is more likely to be discontinued in future. 
in this case it hasn't as it is available still in 4.16 which is latest kernel while writing this.

Comment: I get it, but I have another question: down() and  hung_task_timeout? how to deal with this situation. especially hung_task_panic.

Comment: It depends on situation i.e there are 4 types at your disposal. 1. down_interruptible - acquire the semaphore unless interrupted 2. down_killable - acquire the semaphore unless killed 3. down_trylock - try to acquire the semaphore, without waiting 4. down_timeout - acquire the semaphore within a specified time use as per your reuirement. but to deal with hung_task_panic better approach is down_timeout with realistic timeout so that task is not hanging for semaphore. worst case sem acquire fails.